# Object - Property Best Practices

Tags: .net, oop, properties

I really like being able to organization my objects like this where `Source` is it's own object inside the `Document` object.

**METHOD #1**

```
Dim doc As New Process.Document()
doc.Source.Type = "URL"
doc.Source.Data = "http://myOtherDomain/MyOtherPage.htm"
```

<[View #1 PasteBin Full Code](http://pastebin.com/xnkGsG2P)>

However, is it a better practice to do something like this?

**METHOD #2**

```
Dim doc As New Process.Document()
doc.SourceType = "URL"
doc.SourceData = "http://myOtherDomain/MyOtherPage.htm"
```

<[View #2 PasteBin Full Code](http://pastebin.com/NFuyW5Fy)>

The reason I ask is because it gets a little confusing with the first method because You get this:

`Process.Document.DocumentSource` and `doc.Source`

I think that in method #1, Process.Document.DocumentSource is redundant having Document twice and wish there was a way to hide that object from being selectable in the intellisense dropdown list by the user of the assembly.

But on the flip-side, if you have a LOT of properties, it seems better to be able to group them into sub-objects like method #1 does so you don't have a hundred properties all listed in the Intellisense dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) says Method #2 is the way to go, given just those two options.

A third method could be providing the `Source` object instead of setting `doc.Source.XYZ`.

```
// C# -- don't know VB.Net
var source = new DocumentSource();
...

doc.Source = source;
```

A fourth method would effectively be constructor injection if the `Source` is required.

```
var source = new DocumentSource();
...
var doc = new Process.Document(source);
```

Comment: The link to the "Law of Demeter" is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't think I'm in danger of anything that it is actually trying to protect against in my situation but I would like to venture forward using best practices when possible and that seems to make a good case not to use method #1.

I take it I should apply the same rule to the `Process.Documents.add(doc)` line as well, correct?

Which brings me to another question. Should I put all the objects like `DocumentSource` and `DocumentCollection` at the top namespace level?  And call them `ProcessDocumentSource`, etc. instead?

Comment: RE the other classes:  You probably want them at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is fine, and shouldn't mess up Intellisense at all. The `Process.Document.DocumentSource` is a type (because you're using nested classes), and the `doc.Source` is the property.

That said, it's normally advisable to *not* use nested classes, especially if they're public. I think there's a FxCop rule about that as well. Moving the `Document` class out of `Process`, and the `DocumentSource` class out of `Document` will clean things up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to organize them into logical entities. If `Type` and `Data` are properties that belong to the logical entity `Source`, I would probably use your Method #1. If `Type` and `Data` were more related to the document, I'd store it there.

What seems the most correct to you, should probably be your final choice. In this case. Method #1 seems appropriate to me. Especially if the `Source` also has other properties.